# How to do smooth UI that involves moving/animating objects?

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm working on an application that involves taking a photo with the camera application and then the user is supposed to select just the important part of the picture by dragging a crop rectangle over it.

My question is how to draw this crop rectangle, because it basically involves a dynamic UI environment and I'm not sure how to deal with that. Should I load the photo in OpenGL and use that to draw the rectangle or is it fine to resize a view on touch input (so about 30 times per second)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just draw the rectangle in `onDraw()` method of a custom view.  In `onTouch()` set the rectangle size then call `invalidate()` on the view.  You can draw simple primitives of various colors and alpha values using the passed in `Canvas` object.  It doesn't sound like a very complicated drawing operation, so I'd expect it to be pretty smooth.

Comment: To confirm, yes this is quick... I'm currently drawing arbitrarily complex paths (much more complex than a rectangle) to a canvas and although my current refresh rate is 5fps (thats all I need) theres no reason I couldn't go faster

Answer (score 0):

First do the simplest way (such as just resize). If it animates well enough, don't optimize, because OpenGL, while fast, is a lot more work. Also, 30FPS may not be the minimum acceptable. See how it looks to your eye before deciding on a hard-and-fast performance criterion.